# How to move a sql server express mdf file to a different sql sever express server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I'm trying to move my database.mdf file from a development environment to a SQL Server Express server that is hosted on my VPS - but I can't figure out how to attach the file to my database server. Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sp_attach_db`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx) (or CREATE DATABASE FOR ATTACH) - don't forget to bring the LDF (log) files, too.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you can, but you could use the Sql Studio Management Express, which allows you to connect (and then attach) the database.

Your application could also be using a local instance and directly connect to the database.mdf in the app.data folder.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use detach/attach, the recommended method is to use backup/restore (don't forget: SQL Server backup is online)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224071